# SharePoint workflows cannot automatically start

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-workflow

I'm trying to make a SharePoint workflow start automatically for any new document that is uploaded to a specific doc library. I've configured the workflow in SharePoint Designer to auto start for new documents or changed documents. However, the workflow never starts automatically! I can run it manually, but it won't execute itself.

I've searched around and have found the core issue, which is reflected in my log:

"Declarative workflows cannot automatically start if the triggering action was performed by System Account. Canceling workflow auto-start."

However, all the  fixes I've seen have not worked for me. A common solution is to *not* run or create the workflow as the SharePoint System Account. Well, my SharePoint service accounts are not the ones I'm logging in as to upload my documents nor was it the one I used to create the workflow. I've tried editing & re-publishing my workflow as a totally new account and it still won't auto-start.

Comment: Are you sure that when going to SharePoint your user isn't displayed as `SHAREPOINT\system`? Really do try another user, create a new one if you have to.

Comment: Sure. Just checked. The user is my normal domain account, not the one I have SP services running as. And I did create a brand new user account and used that to save and re-publish my workflow to no avail.

Comment: Try to do iisreset. Maybe some caching issues.

Comment: Do you upload the documents by yourself or is there any workflow/app uploading it in the library?

Comment: I uploaded the documents myself (both as my usual domain account and as a test user account that I created specifically for this).

Answer (score 1):

Just focus on two things:

1. Workflow will never start automatically with system account.
2. Check the options `Start workflow automatically when an item is created or changed` from Workflow Start Options.

Comment: Ok, so workflows will never start automatically when run by the System account. However, from (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee428324(v=office.14).aspx): "The most important security concept to be aware of is that workflows run as part of the system account in SharePoint Server 2010." If that's the case then it doesn't matter what check boxes you select - the job always runs in the context of the system account and therefore will never auto-start even though the check boxes tell it to do so. I'm stumped. I have those checkboxes enabled, but it does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

While publishing the workflow, u need to select the checkbox  `Start workflow automatically when an item is created or changed` for the workflow to start automatically or else whatsoever the WF will not start automatically.

Instead of using Sharepoint system user account, u could use an account having contribute permission on site level and full control over the library

Answer (score 0):

Run the command at the server in powershell

stsadm.exe –o setproperty –propertyname declarativeworkflowautostartonemailenabled –propertyvalue yes

After I did that, the workflow runs perfectly although it shows the created by as being "system account".